# How to make INSERT safer?

Tags: spring, hql, sql-injection, sql-insert

This is my method. As you can see I'm using native sql to execute INSERT queries.

```
public void addNews(String title, String content) {

        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO news VALUES(NULL,:title,:content,NULL)")
                .setString("title", title).setString("content", content);
        int updated = query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Is it safe? Or how can I improve my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting values as parameters (setString() method) preventing from SQL-injections. Non secure sql-statement looks like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO news VALUES(NULL," + title + "," + content + ",NULL)";
```

Read more about SQL injections (and other types of vulnerabilities) you can here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: What if I'll make `+id+` statement(id is Integer)?

Comment: Then if there is any way for user to specify id you can "catch" SQL-injection. E.g. I can put into id input: '1 or 1=1' and from query "Select from users where id=" + id; I get query: "Select from users where id=1 or 1=1" which returns me all users

Comment: Yes. I didn't think about it. Looks like this is quite safe. But for sure better to use query.setInteger()...